# ssh with jsch: non 'simple' command output trailed with unexpected output combined from fragments of the command in use

Tags: java, linux, ssh, jsch

I'm running several commands on ssh using jcraft.jsch channel and I see that whenever I use some complicated command (with regexp or using pipes) the output of the command has an unexpected 'prefix' combined from fragments of the command or the entire command fragmented into small pieces separated with multiple spaces and combined with '<' characters here and there...

example 1:

```
#ls /opt/qb/data2/oscar/process-manager-helper/*/var/core-dump/{2089,2090,2091,2092,2093,2094,2095}.*

ger-helper/*/var/core-dump/{20

<2/oscar/process-manager-helper/*/var/core-dump/{208                         9,2090,2091,2092,ls: cannot access /opt/qb/data2/oscar/process-manager-helper/*/var/core-dump/2090.*: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /opt/qb/data2/oscar/process-manager-helper/*/var/core-dump/2092.*: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /opt/qb/data2/oscar/process-manager-helper/*/var/core-dump/2094.*: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /opt/data2/oscar/process-manager-helper/*/var/core-dump/2095.*: No such file or directory
/opt/qb/data2/oscar/process-manager-helper/0/var/core-dump/2089.20141126-195527.213-00000000-opt.dell.srvadmin.bin.idracadm7.idracadm7.core.gz
/opt/qb/data2/oscar/process-manager-helper/0/var/core-dump/2091.20141126-201557.530-00000000-opt.dell.srvadmin.bin.idracadm7.idracadm7.core.gz
/opt/qb/data2/oscar/process-manager-helper/0/var/core-dump/2093.20141126-202822.524-00000000-opt.dell.srvadmin.bin.idracadm7.idracadm7.core.gz
```

example 2:

```
#du -s --block-size=1 /opt/qb/data2/oscar/process-manager-helper/0/var/core-dump/2089.20141126-195527.213-00000000-opt.dell.srvadmin.bin.idracadm7.idracadm7.core.gz | awk { print $1; }

rvadmin.bin.idracad

<-195527.213-00000000-opt.dell.srvadmin.bin.idracadm                         7.idracadwk

<ell.srvadmin.bin.idracadm7.idracadm7.core.gz | awk                          { print $1; }
86016
```

here's a sample code that reproduces it (at least on my setup):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        JSch myConnection = new JSch();
        myConnection.setKnownHosts("/dev/null");
        Session mySession = myConnection.getSession("root", "my-host.my-lab.com", 2222);
        mySession.setPassword("password123");
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        mySession.setConfig(config);
        mySession.connect(15000);
        Channel myChannel = mySession.openChannel("shell");

        ((ChannelShell) myChannel).setPtyType("exec");
        InputStream fromServer = myChannel.getInputStream();
        OutputStream toServer = myChannel.getOutputStream();

        myChannel.connect();

        String commandString = "du -s --block-size=1 /opt/base/dir/eventLog | awk '{ print $1; }'";
        toServer.write((commandString + "\n").getBytes());
        toServer.flush();

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

        while (true)
        {
            int avail = fromServer.available();
            if (avail > 0)
            {
                while (avail > 0)
                {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[avail];
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    if ((bytesRead = fromServer.read(buf)) < 0)
                    {
                        throw new IOException("connection is probably closed (can't read " + avail + " from server) - return value is " + bytesRead);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
                    {
                        if (buf[i] >= 127 || buf[i] < 9 || (buf[i] >= 14 && buf[i] <= 31) || buf[i] == 11 || buf[i] == 12 || buf[i] == 8)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        result.append((char) buf[i]);
                    }
                    avail = fromServer.available();
                }
                if (result.toString().trim().endsWith("#"))
                {
                    System.out.println(result);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

please advise

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code which you're using to run these commands.

Answer (score 0):

```
Channel myChannel = mySession.openChannel("shell");
((ChannelShell) myChannel).setPtyType("exec");
[...]
String commandString = "du ...";
toServer.write((commandString + "\n").getBytes());
```

You're opening a shell channel, which is normally used for interactive sessions. Then you're writing the command string to the channel's input stream, which emulates typing the characters of the command. This way of running commands will work, but the remote system is going to behave as if this were an interactive terminal session. In particular, the remote shell may print command prompts, and the remote PTY may echo the text which your program is "typing". I think that's what is happening to you--the output of the command which you're running is being mixed with command prompts and character echo.

You should consider using a [`ChannelExec`](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec.html) to run your remote commands instead of a `ChannelShell`. With a ChannelExec, the remote system directly invokes your command (instead of invoking a shell and letting you feed the command to the shell's input). The channel closes when the command exits, and you shouldn't be bothered with character echo or command prompts.

Jsch has a [ChannelExec example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html). Your code would look something like this:

```
ChannelExec chan = mySession.openChannel("exec");
chan.setCommand("du ... | awk ...");
// Set input and output streams
// Request a PTY if you think you need one
chan.connect();
```

`chan.connect()` will open the channel and launch the command on the remote system. The remote command's standard output can be read from the input stream returned by `getInputStream()`, and the command's standard error can be read from the stream returned by `getErrStream()`. Or you can do other things with those streams; see the example.

Comment: first of all - thank you for you answer!

I don't want to use the exec option since the channel remains open and we use it for commands during the entire app lifetime...

regarding the echo chars: I dont get these when working manually and also I dont get these with simple and short commands..

I suspect there is something else...

Comment: The expensive part of using ssh is opening the session. Opening channels isn't expensive, and you can even have more than one channel open at once on the same session. You really should consider opening an exec channel for each command.